# echo out image variable in conditional statement

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to display an image in a conditional statement.

Without the condition I can simply do:

```
<div>
    <img src="<?php echo($img); ?>" />
</div>
```

But lets say that i have condition like this:

```
<?php
    if ($img ) {
       echo "image exists";

        // Show image

        } else {
        echo "no image..";

        }
?>
```

I am using wordpress and the `$img`contains a url.
Help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php if !empty($img) { // check if $img not empty ?>
 <div> <!-- display image -->
    <img src="<?php echo($img); ?>" />
 </div>
<?php } else { // if $img empty 'no image' show message 
        echo "no image..";
      }
?>
```

Comment: you have to check if (file_get_contents($img) ) or  if (file_exists($img)) , because if file is not available on serrver then it will gives you error

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
if (!empty($img) && file_get_contents($img) ) {
       echo "image exists";

        // Show image

        } else {
        echo "no image..";

        }
```